# Dynamically Set the timer duedate in JBPM process definition

Tags: java, jboss, jbpm, business-process-management

JBPM(3.x) that i was using doesn't support changing the timer due date dynamically. Once the process definition is created in JBPM, all the instances of that process definition uses the same timer.

Can I update the timer dynamically before entering to the node?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using CustomJBPMHandler we can update the JBPM tables at instance level but this is not a advisable approach. Look in to JBPM5.x API for any methods exposed for updating the `duedate` of the timer.

Use the `org.jbpm.graph.def.ActionHandler` to create your own TaskHandler.